OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error when trying to connect a TCA9548A I2C multiplexer
I connected a TCA9548A multiplexer to a Raspberry Pi 4B. The connections are as follows:
Raspberry Pi  --->  TCA9548A
5V            --->  VIN
GND           --->  GND
GPIO2 (SDA1)  --->  SDA
GPIO3 (SCL1)  --->  SCL
Running the i2cdetect command in the terminal gives me the expected hexadecimal address, as shown below.
i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- 71 -- -- -- -- -- -- 

I've been running the sample code provided by adafruit, but it just doesn't seem to work.
# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2021 Carter Nelson for Adafruit Industries
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

# This example shows using TCA9548A to perform a simple scan for connected devices
import board
import adafruit_tca9548a
import time

# Create I2C bus as normal
i2c = board.I2C()  # uses board.SCL and board.SDA
# i2c = board.STEMMA_I2C()  # For using the built-in STEMMA QT connector on a microcontroller
time.sleep(1)

# Create the TCA9548A object and give it the I2C bus
tca = adafruit_tca9548a.TCA9548A(i2c)
time.sleep(1)

for channel in range(8):
    if tca[channel].try_lock():
        print("Channel {}:".format(channel), end="")
        addresses = tca[channel].scan()
        print([hex(address) for address in addresses if address != 0x71])
        tca[channel].unlock()

I keep getting the error below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mealworm/Latest_SSM/delete_i2c_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    if tca[channel].try_lock():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit_tca9548a.py", line 62, in try_lock
    self.tca.i2c.writeto(self.tca.address, self.channel_switch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/busio.py", line 203, in writeto
    return self._i2c.writeto(address, buffer, stop=stop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py", line 52, in writeto
    self._i2c_bus.write_bytes(address, buffer[start:end])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 303, in write_bytes
    self._device.write(buf)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

Is there any reason why this would happen?

Ask Adafruit how to use their bizarre code; more productively look for some normal code. Why do you think you need a I²C multiplexer?

Raspberry Pi OS has a dtoverlay for I²C bus multiplexers.
Name:   i2c-mux

Info:   Adds support for a number of I2C bus multiplexers on i2c_arm

Usage:  dtoverlay=i2c-mux,<param>=<val>

Params: pca9542                 Select the NXP PCA9542 device

        pca9545                 Select the NXP PCA9545 device

        pca9548                 Select the NXP PCA9548 device

        addr                    Change I2C address of the device (default 0x70)

        base                    Set an explicit base value for the channel bus
                                numbers

        i2c0                    Choose the I2C0 bus on GPIOs 0&1

        i2c_csi_dsi             Choose the I2C0 bus on GPIOs 44&45

        i2c3                    Choose the I2C3 bus (configure with the i2c3
                                overlay - BCM2711 only)

        i2c4                    Choose the I2C3 bus (configure with the i2c3
                                overlay - BCM2711 only)

        i2c5                    Choose the I2C5 bus (configure with the i2c4
                                overlay - BCM2711 only)

        i2c6                    Choose the I2C6 bus (configure with the i2c6
                                overlay - BCM2711 only)

        disconnect_on_idle      Force the mux to disconnect all child buses
                                after every transaction.

